# how to compare 1 group_id with multiple user group_ids in django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have a table contain groupid column. now I need to retrieve data based on this groupid.
but my problem is i am able to retrieve this if the user belongs to only one group, if he belongs more than 1 group how to query it in django.

my query is like

```
user = request.user
usrid=request.user.id
urls = models.Urls.objects.select_for_update().filter(
        inReview=0).filter(groupId=request.user.groups.get().id).order_by('priority','id')     [:claim_count]
```

Can any one suggest how to filter based on `groupid`. In sql :

```
select * from url where groupid in (select groupid from auth_user_groups where userid=usrid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is not valid.

Why not just use `__in` as you do in your SQL?

```
Urls.objects.filter(inReview=0).filter(groupId__in=user.groups.values_list('id'))
```